# If $N \unlhd G$ where G is finite, then $a^k \in N$ for all $a \in G$. $k=[G:N]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose G is a finite group and $N \unlhd G$ with $[G:N]=k$. Prove that $a^k \in N$ for all $a \in G$.

All i know is that if G is a finite group, then $[G:N]=\frac{|G|}{|N|}$. But can i actually use this information to show the result?

Or how can i prove this result?

Comment: Consider $(aN)^k$ in the group $G/N$. What does Lagrange say?

Comment: @BenWest what does $(aN)^k$ represent?

Comment: It's the product of $aN$ with itself $k$ times. Since $N$ is normal, $G/N$ is a group, with operation $gN\cdot hN=ghN$, so $(aN)^k=a^kN$.

Comment: I am sure this must be a duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

Since $N$ is normal and $[G:N]=k$, then $G/N$ is a group of order $k$. So $[a^k]=[0]$ in $G/N$, i.e., $a^k\in N$.

Comment: What does the notation "[$a^k$]" mean?

Comment: The class of $a^k$ in $G/N$. In general it is represented by $(aN)^k$, as @BenWest said.

Comment: if $[a^k]$ means $(aN)^k$, then what does [0] mean?

Comment: The identity of the group, $N$.

Comment: why does $|G/N|=k$ imply that $a^k=1_N$?

Comment: It doesn't true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Definition